# Azure devops Server 2019 - Error while creating Workitem states

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2019, azure-rest-api

I am trying to create a state for existing work item.

For Get, the url will show the list of States under Bug.

But am facing an issue when I do Post with json.

```
https://{server}/{collection}/_apis/work/processes/{processid}/workItemTypes/Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.Bug/states?api-version=5.0-preview.1
```

Json:

```
{"name": "Test-Status", "color": "007acc", "stateCategory": "InProgress", "order": 3 }
```

Below is the error details

> Http - 404 - NotFound
>
> { "$id": "1", "innerException": null, "message": "VS402805: Cannot
>   find work item type with reference name
>   'Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.Bug' in process named
>   'dcdcc713-ebc6-4940-aa9d-d6c9d3e00e39'.", "typeName":
>   "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server.Metadata.ProcessWorkItemTypeDoesNotExistException,
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server", "typeKey":
>   "ProcessWorkItemTypeDoesNotExistException", "errorCode": 0, "eventId":
>   3200 }

Any help regarding this is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem should be:`Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.Bug`. I think you need use the format like `processName.typeName`. In addition the original process cannot be customized , only the inherited process can be customized.

Here I test your api in postman,it can work well.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, this helps to fix my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

When you create a new process, all the Work Item Types from the Parente process (Agile, Scrum, etc.) starts with the Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.(Epic, Bug, etc.) and you can't modify it, you will have the error:

"VS402805: Cannot find work item type with reference name 'Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.Bug' in process name ..."

To solve this, you just need to create a new work item type that inherits that work item type that you want to use, post example:

POST [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/work/processes/{processId}/workitemtypes?api-version=6.0-preview.2](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/_apis/work/processes/%7BprocessId%7D/workitemtypes?api-version=6.0-preview.2)

```
{

  "referenceName": "ProcessName.Issue",

  "name": "Issue",

  "description": "your description",

  "color": "B4009E",

  "icon": "icon_traffic_cone",

  "inheritsFrom": "Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.Issue"

}
```

I hope it helps.

Have a nice day!